# How can you prove that "Christian miracles" are false?

Tags: quran, christianity, miracles

As muslims, we believe that the Quran is the eternal miracle of Allah and hence, it is the ultimate proof of the truth. However, a christian may make a similar claim about their holy spirit miracles, like healing the blind, speaking in many tongues, etc. Likewise, a christian might even say "Maybe our gospels are also miracles. We just don't know it yet."

So how can I prove it to myself that these so-called "christian miracles" are false or invalid?

Comment: Two problems here. First, this question is not about Islam, so it doesn't fit Islam SE. Second, it's broad, so it doesn't fit in SE in general. Do you have a specific "miracle" in mind? If so, maybe ask on the Skepticism SE (I'd double check that, I've never posted there so I don't know for sure what their rules for on topic are)

Comment: Christians often say Jesus' incarnation or resurrection are *the* cardinal miracle of history, or the ultimate standard of truth. See for example C. S. Lewis' essay "[The Grand Miracle](http://www.orthodoxytoday.org/blog/2014/05/christianity-is-one-great-miracle-the-grand-miracle-by-c-s-lewis/)". However, as a Christian, I've never heard such claims about what you call "Holy Spirit miracles" and I have never heard anything like a claim that the gospels might be miracles too. This question would be improved if it focused on claims you've actually heard, rather than hypotheticals.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude By holy spirit miracles, I'm referring to faith healing by christian priests

Comment: I understood that. I stand by everything I said previously.

Comment: The same way you evaluate any claims to miracles and find them to be fraudulent: you demand evidence that you can scrutinize and test, and if they dance around and put on a show without letting you look at every bit you want to look at, you discard their claims.

Comment: This is just too vague to be readily answerable under the Stack Exchange model: I would strongly recommend you check the advice in our help centre pages on [ask] and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) to better understand the sorts of questions we encourage here.